# How to get rows containg empty list in a Data Frame Columns in Python

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
    test = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B'])
    test.loc[0,'A'] = 'a'
    test.loc[0,'B'] = []
    test.loc[1,'A'] = 'b'
    test.loc[1,'B'] = ['a','b']
```

I want to get another data frame which contains the rows when column 'B' containing an empty list. What's the pythonic way of doing it?

```
    A    B
0   a   []
```

Many thanks

Comment: If you don't have empty strings, you can use `test[test['B'].str.len()==0]`

Comment: Yes, it seems to work, I tried len() in different position and didn't work out for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As empty lists are going to be interpreted as collections to be processed in a vectorized way, I don't see any way to test it but to drill down to an `apply` call:

```
test.B.apply(lambda c: c==[])
Out[71]: 
0     True
1    False
Name: B, dtype: bool

test[test.B.apply(lambda c: c==[])]
Out[72]: 
   A   B
0  a  []
```

Answer (score 2):

Empty lists translate to False as a boolean.  Using `~` to convert that to True is a simple trick.  It's easy to read and runs pretty fast for me.  Definitely faster than using `len()`.

```
test[~test['B'].astype(bool)]

   A   B
0  a  []
```